# How to filter in menu by li parent what is inside the ul child of li?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

How to filter when typing 'process' it and everything that is inside it?

[image]

This my HTML:

input search

```
  <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control filter-search" placeholder="Buscar..." autocomplete="off" id="mySearch">
      <button class="btn_clear">x</button>
  </div>
```

this side_bar

```
   <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree" id="myMenu">
    <li class="treeview menu-open" id="mainProcessesNav">
        <a class="menuhref" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>
            <span><?= $this->lang->line('application_daily_process'); ?></span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
         </a>
         <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <?php if (in_array('viewTrackingOrder', $user_permission)) : ?>
            <li id="semFreteNav" data-search="<?= $this->lang->line('application_daily_process'); ?>" >">
                <a class="menuhref" href="<?php echo base_url('orders/semfrete') ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> <?= $this->lang->line('application_freight_to_wire'); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My filter in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mySearch").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myMenu li a").filter(function() {
           $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
        });
       if($("#myMenu li a:visible").length > 0){
            $("#emptyMsg").hide();
       }else{
            $("#emptyMsg").show();
       }
      });
});
```

I thought about adding the name of the parent `$(this).data("search").val()` inside a `data-search="name of the parent"` and trying to filter by it in jQuery But it didn't work. Can someone help me please?

The idea is when typing the name of the father it stays open and lists all the children and hides all the others.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would advise that you target the LI instead of the A. Also this is not how .filter() works. You need to `return` a `true` or `false` and that will help reduce the set of elements. Then you need to do something to the filtered set. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#mySearch").on("keyup", function(event) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      console.log("Starting Filter");
      var term = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      console.log("Filter for: " + term);
      $(".treeview-menu > li.semFreteNav").each(function(i, el) {
        if ($(el).text().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1) {
          console.log("Found");
          $(el).show();
        } else {
          $(el).hide();
        }
      });
    } else {
      $(".treeview-menu > li.semFreteNav").show();
    }
  });

  $(".input-group button.btn_clear").click(function() {
    $("#mySearch").val("").trigger("keyup");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control filter-search" placeholder="Buscar..." autocomplete="off" id="mySearch">
  <button class="btn_clear">x</button>
</div>
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree" id="myMenu">
  <li class="treeview menu-open" id="mainProcessesNav">
    <a class="menuhref" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>
      <span>Processos</span>
      <span class="pull-right-container"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li class="semFreteNav" data-search="">
        <a class="menuhref" href="#someplace"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Fretas</a>
      </li>
      <li class="semFreteNav" data-search="">
        <a class="menuhref" href="#someplace"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Pedidios</a>
      </li>
      <li class="semFreteNav" data-search="">
        <a class="menuhref" href="#someplace"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Módulo</a>
      </li>
      <li class="semFreteNav" data-search="">
        <a class="menuhref" href="#someplace"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Erros</a>
      </li>
      <li class="semFreteNav" data-search="">
        <a class="menuhref" href="#someplace"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Administrar</a>
      </li>
      <li class="semFreteNav" data-search="">
        <a class="menuhref" href="#someplace"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Produtos</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can use Filter, yet it might be better to use Each.

HTML requires that all IDs be unique. Your PHP code would create a large number of IDs that are all the same. This can also cause various issues for JS/jQuery. I switched them to Class.